# Android WebView playing audio with javascript

Tags: javascript, android, audio, webview

I'm trying to very quickly port over an html application with plays sound (with soundmanager2) to a native android app using WebView. From my research, I haven't seen any evidence that sound, such as mp3s, can be played via javascript or any other methods using WebView.

My goal now is to quickly port over the html app and then eventually create a truely native application without using WebViews.

Please let me know if anyone has been able to successfully implement playing audio using WebViews and Javascript or if this is just not possible at this time.

Thank you.

Comment: I think a found a nice workaround for it. Check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/40634355/3866399

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play around with this:

```
if(cm.message().contains("play sound")) {
    //String[] temp = cm.message().split("#");
    AudioManager audiomanager= (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    float actualvolume = (float) audiomanager.getStreamVolume (AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    float maxVolume= (float) audiomanager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    float volume = actualvolume/maxVolume;

    if (loaded) {
        soundPool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 54, 1f);
        Log.e("Test", "Played sound");
    }
} else if(cm.message().contains("stop sound")) {
    soundPool.stop(1);
    Log.e("Test","stoped");
}

myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/timer.html");
soundID = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.sound1,1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Would this work for you?

```
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.endsWith(".ogg")){
                Log.d(TAG, "Reproducir archivo OGG");
                Uri tempPath = Uri.parse(url);
                MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(WebViewVideo.this, tempPath);
                player.start();
                return true;
            }else{
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
        }

    });
```

If you really want to use Javascript, you can try with document.open() or something like that, I haven't tried so, but I guess it would work the same way.

By the way, this is the case that you want to play that audio on background, if you want to show the actual player, I think you have to implement the View by yourself.

And if you were considering html5 audio tag, forget it. AFAIK Froyo doesn't support it in any way.

I hope this helps and it's not too late.

Regards.

Comment: I'm trying to use this , but i'm not sure what to use instead of "WebViewVideo.this"