# Asset Manager, OpenFd?

Tags: android

I have a file in my assets folder I wish to access, I do so by:

```
AssetFileDescriptor fileSound = am.openFd("myfilepathetc/mymp3.mp3");
```

But I get the error:

```
This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed
```

After some googling it appears that I need to add an extension to my file, such as .mp3 as Android compresses stuff in the assets folder unless its of a format already compressed, the only problem is, my file is already an mp3 and it still wont open.

Is there a way of uncompromising it? Or does anyone have a better way to access an mp3 from assets, please note I do not want to access it from the raw folder for reasons i wont bother going into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use this instead :

```
private void playAudioSound() {
    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getAssets().openFd("sounds/jad0005a.wav");
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor());
        player.prepare();
        player.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: That gives me an input stream. How can I use that with sound pool?

Comment: And teh file is still compressed

Comment: Nice, but see this for proper setDataSource call with 2 additional params:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13786202/525319

Answer (score 0):

how are you? I know that it is an old question, but I was with the same issue and I found that workaround very useful.

Java class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;

public class AudioInterface {
    Context mContext;

    AudioInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    //Play an audio file from the webpage
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void playAudio(String aud) { //String aud - file name passed 
                                        //from the JavaScript function
        final MediaPlayer mp;

              try {
                  AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = 
                        mContext.getAssets().openFd(aud);
                                  mp = new MediaPlayer();
                                  mp.setDataSource(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), 
                                  fileDescriptor.getStartOffset(), 
                                  fileDescriptor.getLength());
                                  fileDescriptor.close();
                                  mp.prepare();
                                  mp.start();
              } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                              e.printStackTrace();
                  } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                              e.printStackTrace();
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                              e.printStackTrace();
              } 
    }
}
```

Javascrip file:

```
AndAud.playAudio("audio/One.mp3");
```

On your java WebView:

```
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new AudioInterface(this), "AndAud");
```

Ref: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/677841/Playing-Audio-on-Android-from-an-HTML-File

Comment: JavaScript ?! That's not related to the question