# Setting a file from asset folder causes MediaPlayer to nullpointer exception

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a list of asset folder files, named **filelist**. I show all that elements in the ListView, so when some of them has been clicked i want it to be played. And here it gives me **nullpointerexception**. Code, that causes an error:

```
 try {                          
selectedItemPlayer.setDataSource(
    aMan.openFd(filelist[selectedItem]).getFileDescriptor(),
    aMan.openFd(filelist[selectedItem]).getStartOffset(),
    aMan.openFd(filelist[selectedItem]).getLength());
    selectedItemPlayer.prepare();
                        selectedItemPlayer.start();
                        selectedItemPlayer.setLooping(false);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
   ...
   ...
```

**aMan** is *assetManager*, **filelist** is the list of asset directory files, **selectedItem** is the element that has been clicled at the list and which i want to play. SO when I click to the list-item it crashes with nullPointerException. Seems, sounds not loading to mediaplayer. Strange, because I use **filelist**, with soundPool and it works fine... ANy idea?

UPD1: Logcat message

```
    12-09 14:17:06.964: W/dalvikvm(23404): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2b542210)
    12-09 14:17:06.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23404): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    12-09 14:17:06.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23404): java.lang.NullPointerException
    12-09 14:17:06.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23404):    at uk.co.futurelite.elite.drum.machine.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:251)
    12-09 14:17:06.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23404):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:924)
    12-09 14:17:06.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23404):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
    12-09 14:17:06.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23404):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1065)
    12-09 14:17:06.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23404):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2522)
    12-09 14:17:06.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23404):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3183)
    12-09 14:17:06.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23404):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    12-09 14:17:06.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23404):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    12-09 14:17:06.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23404):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    12-09 14:17:06.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23404):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
    12-09 14:17:06.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23404):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    12-09 14:17:06.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23404):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    12-09 14:17:06.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23404):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    12-09 14:17:06.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23404):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    12-09 14:17:06.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23404):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

UPD2:
At line 251 i have the following code

```
    selectedItemPlayer.setDataSource(aMan.openFd(filelist[selectedItem]).getFileDescriptor(),
```

**filelist[selectedItem]** cant be null, because i just printed it in logcat

```
    12-09 14:31:58.442: V/TESTing filelist(1819): dk9_ch.WAV
```

Dont know...

UPD3: now it works, thanks to Luksprog , I was supposed to initialize it. Didnt know.

Comment: Always post the stacktrace with the exception you get from `Logcat`.

Comment: @Luksprog, i have updated my question, pls have a look )

Comment: Something is `null` at the line `251` in `MainActivity`. If you can share which is that line then you'll be one step near in solving the problem.

Comment: @Luksprog, i have my code updated, see UPD2

Comment: What about `selectedItemPlayer` and `aMan`, did you test them for `null`?

Comment: @Luksprog, aMan is not null because I use it in soundPool as follow-->`mSoundPoolMap.put(RAW_1_1, mSoundPool.load(aMan.openFd(filelist[0]), 1));` and It works perfect. about selectedItemPlayer hwo to test it for null? It is public variable in the activity...

Comment: Right before line `251` add a `Log` line and print each of the variables used on the problematic line and see which one is `null`.

Comment: @Luksprog, i pass only one variable which is filelist[selectedItem], and i can print it, it is not null. line 251 is in upd2, seems it just doesnt assign it to mediaplayer.

Comment: Place this line : `Log.e("Look for me!!", "Which one is null : " + selectedItemPlayer + " " + aMan + " " + filelist[selectedItem]);` before the `try-catch` block from the code you posted. And check the logcat.

Comment: @Luksprog, ok so selectedItemPlayer is null... and?) I only created it in the mainActivity and the first place where i use it it is line 251..

Comment: You always must assign a valid reference or instantiate a new object before using it. Please have a look at the guide for media on the android site http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

Comment: @Luksprog, so i was just supposed to add one line `selectedItemPlayer = new MediaPlayer();`. Now it works, thanks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Break your code as below to help track your problem*

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd(filelist[selectedItem]);
selectedItemPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
```

It seems that `filelist[selectedItem]` returns null or it doesnt exist in your assets foldre. Check your main activity at line 251

Comment: Did you make an instance of the selectedItemPlayer before this line?

Comment: I have selectedItemPlayer as a public variable in the activity

Comment: Did you check if it is null or not? It is the only way to know.

Comment: how would you check it if it is null or not? if it is null, what would you do after? i confused...

Comment: if( selectedItemPlayer == null ){  log.d()} If it is null you have to create an instance first: selectedItemPlayer = new MediaPlayer();