# Not able to play audio using javascript in webview in android

Tags: android, html5-audio

On Android phone, audio is playing when i used the following code in html file, but when i remove the "autoplay" attribute i am unable to play the audio on webview. Does anyone has solution for this?

```
<audio id="audiotag1"  style="display:none" preload="auto" hidden='true' autoplay>
</audio>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var audio1 = document.getElementById("audiotag1");
    audio1.src = "file:///sdcard/Music/intro.mp3";
    audio1.type = "audio/mpeg";
    audio1.play();
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try this var clickSound = new Audio('click.mp3');
clickSound.play();

Comment: In webview, if i use the new Audio() and object.play(), then also it is not playing the audio. This time i will get error as MediaPlayer error(-1,2467...);
So i used the audio tag.

Comment: I think I found a good workaround for it. Check this out!
http://stackoverflow.com/a/40634355/3866399

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this code snippet

```
    //String[] temp = cm.message().split("#");
    AudioManager audiomanager= (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    float actualvolume = (float) audiomanager.getStreamVolume (AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    float maxVolume= (float) audiomanager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    float volume = actualvolume/maxVolume;

    if (loaded) {
        soundPool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 54, 1f);
        Log.e("Test", "Played sound");
    }
} else if(cm.message().contains("stop sound")) {
    soundPool.stop(1);
    Log.e("Test","stoped");
}

myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/timer.html");
soundID = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.sound1,1);
```

Look at this link

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_media_media.md.html

Comment: Thanks for the solution Vaibs_Cool, but i want to play the audio from javascript object not from android object.

Comment: Audio is playing when i use the cordova api's, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using an audio library like [SoundJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/SoundJS) to make this easier for you.

Hope that helps.