# Play mp3 from mp3 url automatically in Webview android

Tags: android, url, webview, android-webview, mp3

I have a mp3 url which works perfectly. It also plays the song automatically when opened in Chrome PC version. But when the same link is open in Webview android I need to provided gesture to play.(I have enabled Javascript)

Comment: Have you disabled javascript?

Comment: I have enabled Javascript.Should I disable it?

Comment: Generally you should. I thought perhaps you were using javascript to autoplay the content and since it is common practice to disable js for Android `WebView`'s I thought that perhaps enabling it would clear the issue.

Comment: How are you handling autoplay in your web page. There is also possibility of injecting js code in the webview if autoplay doesn't start.

Comment: you might wanna look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19157876/not-able-to-play-audio-using-javascript-in-webview-in-android

Comment: Do you can play any sound ? Or do you have a problem with autoplaying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was done by the function of webview.

```
 webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
 webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Done by try and error. :)