# Playing sound in WebView from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, webview, audio

I'm trying to play sound from JavaScript code loaded to WebView from assets:

```
WebView web_view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
web_view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web_view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
web_view.loadUrl("file:///assets/www/index.html");
```

I tried all combinations of following ways how to play audio with OGG, MP3 and WAV files, the JavaSrcipt code is in assets/www/js/play.js:

```
audio = new Audio("../audio/sound.mp3");
audio.load();
audio.play();

audio = new Audio("./audio/sound.mp3");
audio.load();
audio.play();

audio = new Audio("audio/sound.mp3");
audio.load();
audio.play();

audio = new Audio("file:///android_asset/www/audio/sound.mp3");
audio.load();
audio.play();

audio = new Audio();
audio.src = document.getElementById("audio_tag").src;
audio.load();
audio.play();
```

Where audio_tag is `<audio id="audio_tag" src="audio/sound.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>`, also tried with all combinations of paths and formats.

But the sound is not playing and only clue what may be wrong is following general error:

> E/MediaPlayer(1530): error (1, -2147483648)

Guessing from this info message, the path to audio file should be correct for second trough fifth case:

```
I/StagefrightPlayer(33): setDataSource('file:///android_asset/www/audio/sound.mp3');
```

Although this question may be considered as duplicate of 
[Android WebView playing audio with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795276/android-webview-playing-audio-with-javascript) and the answer is not helping anyhow since shouldOverrideUrlLoading is never called, I'm trying to specify this problem more precisely here.

Do you have any clue what may be wrong or how to find out what is it?

Thank you.

Edit: Testing in Galaxy Gio with Android 2.3 gives me different set of errors though:

> 02-06 17:15:13.829: V/PlayerDriver(95): AddToScheduler    02-06
>   17:15:13.829: V/PlayerDriver(95): PendForExec    02-06 17:15:13.829:
>   V/PlayerDriver(95): OsclActiveScheduler::Current    02-06
>   17:15:13.829: V/PlayerDriver(95): StartScheduler    02-06
>   17:15:13.829: V/PVPlayer(95): send PLAYER_SETUP    02-06 17:15:13.829:
>   V/PlayerDriver(95): Send player code: 2    02-06 17:15:13.829:
>   V/PlayerDriver(95): CommandCompleted    02-06 17:15:13.829:
>   V/PlayerDriver(95): Completed command PLAYER_SETUP status=PVMFSuccess 
>   02-06 17:15:13.829: V/PVPlayer(95):
>   setDataSource(file:///android_asset/www/audio/sound.mp3)    02-06
>   17:15:13.839: V/PVPlayer(95): prepareAsync    02-06 17:15:13.839:
>   V/PVPlayer(95):   data source =
>   file:///android_asset/www/audio/sound.mp3    02-06 17:15:13.849:
>   V/PlayerDriver(95): Send player code: 3    02-06 17:15:13.849:
>   V/PlayerDriver(95): handleSetDataSource    02-06 17:15:13.849:
>   V/PlayerDriver(95): handleSetDataSource- scanning for extension
>   02-06 17:15:13.849: V/PlayerDriver(95): HandleInformationalEvent:
>   PVMFInfoErrorHandlingStart    02-06 17:15:13.849: V/PlayerDriver(95):
>   HandleInformationalEvent: type=26 UNHANDLED    02-06 17:15:13.849:
>   W/MediaPlayer(4361): info/warning (1, 26)    02-06 17:15:13.849:
>   V/PlayerDriver(95): CommandCompleted    02-06 17:15:13.849:
>   V/PlayerDriver(95): Completed command PLAYER_SET_DATA_SOURCE
>   status=PVMFErrNotSupported    02-06 17:15:13.849: E/PlayerDriver(95):
>   Command PLAYER_SET_DATA_SOURCE completed with an error or info
>   PVMFErrNotSupported    02-06 17:15:13.849: E/MediaPlayer(4361): error
>   (1, -4)    02-06 17:15:13.849: V/PVPlayer(95): run_init s=-2147483648,
>   cancelled=0    02-06 17:15:13.849: V/PlayerDriver(95):
>   HandleInformationalEvent: PVMFInfoErrorHandlingComplete    02-06
>   17:15:13.849: W/PlayerDriver(95): PVMFInfoErrorHandlingComplete
>   02-06 17:15:13.939: I/MediaPlayer(4361): Info (1,26)    02-06
>   17:15:13.939: E/MediaPlayer(4361): Error (1,-4)    02-06 17:15:13.939:
>   V/PVPlayer(95): reset    02-06 17:15:13.939: V/PlayerDriver(95): Send
>   player code: 18    02-06 17:15:13.939: V/PlayerDriver(95):
>   handleCancelAllCommands    02-06 17:15:13.939: V/PlayerDriver(95):
>   CommandCompleted    02-06 17:15:13.939: V/PlayerDriver(95): Completed
>   command PLAYER_CANCEL_ALL_COMMANDS status=PVMFSuccess    02-06
>   17:15:13.939: V/PlayerDriver(95): Send player code: 11    02-06
>   17:15:13.939: V/PlayerDriver(95): handleReset    02-06 17:15:13.939:
>   V/PlayerDriver(95): CommandCompleted    02-06 17:15:13.939:
>   V/PlayerDriver(95): Completed command PLAYER_RESET status=PVMFSuccess 
>   02-06 17:15:13.939: V/PlayerDriver(95): Send player code: 17    02-06
>   17:15:13.939: V/PlayerDriver(95): handleRemoveDataSource    02-06
>   17:15:13.939: V/PlayerDriver(95): CommandCompleted    02-06
>   17:15:13.939: V/PlayerDriver(95): Completed command
>   PLAYER_REMOVE_DATA_SOURCE status=PVMFSuccess    02-06 17:15:13.939:
>   V/PlayerDriver(95): remove datasource complete    02-06 17:15:13.939:
>   V/PVPlayer(95): unmap file

Comment: think I found an wonderful workaround for this. Please, check my answer here **http://stackoverflow.com/a/40634355/3866399**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and finally i'm using phonegap and cordova where you can play and record audios easily:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_media_media.md.html

Answer (score 6):

Re: MediaPlayer( ): Error (1,-2147483648)

The Android MediaPlayer needs the media files to be world-readable so they can’t reside in the “assets” folder inside the Eclipse project. Push the audio/video files onto the device external storage. To do this, with an emulator, use the DDMS Perspective in Eclipse (while your emulator is running go to Window->Open Prospective->Other->DDMS) to create a folder and push files onto SD card image or internal (non-removable) storage.

Reference on DDMS:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html

In DDMs, select your emulator in the Devices panel on the left, and then choose the FileExplorer tab on the right, look for a folder named /mnt/sdcard/ which contains the SDCard contents, or, alternatively /Android/data/package_name/files/ for the standardized application’s storage area. So, in the above example, if you create a folder myaudio on the SDcard the filename path would be:

audio = new Audio("/mnt/sdcard/myaudio/sound.mp3");

Reference:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

And don't give up on HTML5!

Comment: Great! Many thanks for the explanation. Unfortunately, this solution seems quite hacky to me. I don't want to spoil user's SD card with any files. Maybe storing those files to application's temporary storage would be fine but this is not world-readable place, right? Furthermore, since there are relative links to sounds throughout the project, I'd need to extract the HTML and JS files too which I also don't want to. I'm fine with playing sounds with native calls for now.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your Android device and the available codecs... But probably the path is not correct. Are you using Phonegap? Does your code play on desktop browsers?

I'm using a similar code:

```
var myAudio = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
myAudio.pause();
myAudio.src = file;
myAudio.play();
```

And my HTML audio tag is this:

```
<audio id="audio" src="" type="audio/mpeg" preload="metadata" ontimeupdate="timeUpdate()"
   ondurationchange="durationChange()" onerror="musicError()" onended="musicEnded()">
<embed src="" height=50 width=100></embed>
```

I'm using mp3 audio file format because it works for iOS and some Android devices.

Also, notice that Audio tag element is not available on all android versions. As you can see [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio), it works for Android 2.3 and up.

Comment: Thank you for another way how to play sounds I haven't tried before. Also thank you for mentioning PhoneGap library. It seems very interesting and I'll try it. I'm testing in Android 2.3 emulator. But even your solution behaves the same.

Comment: The asset URI is printed correcty in the log even if it is specified relatively in JavaScript code so I don't think this is the problem. Also it works pretty fine in all desktop browsers.

Comment: Nothing helped so far, so I workarounded the problem by playing sounds in native code. I'll focus on a real cause of the problem later...