# sencha touch 2.0 application on android device not working

Tags: android, sencha-touch-2

I have created an application in sencha touch2.0 when i run it on android i get a media player error and my application hang up
error details is as follows

```
07-23 11:35:28.863: E/MediaPlayer(29241): Error (1,-2147483648)
```

what is the problem audio is not playing

i am using mp3 format for audio

Comment: i have also same problem

Comment: This answer might help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162022/playing-sound-in-webview-from-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Betteu u can use Iframe in sencha it will support all devices  ..

Like this You Try..

```
              {
                        xtype:"label",
                        left:5,
                        html:'<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="300" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/......" frameborder="0"></iframe>',

                      },
```

first Embed the video and try this one...