# How to play WebView music in background?

Tags: android

I've searched for answer, found something but nothing fixed my problem. So I'm asking here. How should I make WebView play music in background?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Playing sound in WebView from JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162022/playing-sound-in-webview-from-javascript)