# Is it possible to play sound notification on webview?

Tags: javascript, webview

I'm creating a webserver on raspi that can be access by my webview in android phone. This is my JS.

```
setInterval(function() {

    notif();
    $("#position").load('refresh.php');

},1000);

function notif() {

    var pos = $('.status').text();
    var audio = new Audio('alarm.mp3');

    if(pos == "Out") {
    audio.play();
    }
}
```

When I access my webserver from different laptop it plays the audio. But it is not working on android application webview even in browser. I tried to put the  audio.play(); code in a button and open it in a webview and its working fine. Is it a webview problem or js Can you help me. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can find some help here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795276/android-webview-playing-audio-with-javascript

Comment: My sound notif is working on browser on pc. But in android, its not working. I think the link you gave me is creating notif in android studio

Answer (score 0):

you can override onJsAlert() method of WebChromeClient

```
        webView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient(){
            override fun onJsAlert(view: WebView,  url: String,  message: String, result: JsResult): Boolean {
                //play your sound here
                return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result)
            }
        }
```